# function in models.py into admin, so I can control

Tags: django

I have a model like this this

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def get_vote_count(self):
        """This function is intended to return count of voted on thread.
        :return: The sum of vote, upvote - devote
        """
        vote_count = self.vote_set.filter(is_up=True).count() - self.vote_set.filter(is_up=False).count() +1
        if vote_count >= 0:
            return "+ " + str(vote_count)
        else:
            return "- " + str(abs(vote_count))
```

and the vote_count is being displayed as such; post.get_vote_count and I would like to be able to control that in my admin.py.

I tried it like this

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['vote_count']

    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

but nothing is being shown, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using moidel methods, you need to add them to the readonly_fields list as well.

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['vote_count']
    readonly_fields = ['vote_count']
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: thank you but I'm not getting a control, it just shows the value of vote_count

Comment: If you need it to be editable, you will need to add it as a model field (like title).

Comment: hmm can you give me some ideas how I should do it?I tried vote_count=IntegerField but this won't give me any control it was just same as before

Comment: vote_count = models.IntegerField(), below title. You will need to run make migrations, and migrate so that it alters the database. Though looking at your code, I am guessing you didn't post all of the model.

Comment: yeah I didn't post all of them, hmm instead of vote_count I'm putting get_vote_count/////but it won't work. with vote_count readonly_fields gives me error, do you mind looking at my code I posted in the question?i should use get_vote_count right?

Comment: Can you post it as another question, as I am not sure what you are actually trying to achieve now. You can display model methods as read only field. Or you can display normal fields that can be editable (or read only). Plus, is there any reason for checking if the vote count is negative, turning it positive then adding a '-' sign?

Comment: I just made a new question about this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919536/how-to-control-the-out-of-a-function-in-models-py-in-admin-py

Comment: any help would be really appreciated