# how to control the out of a function in models.py in admin.py

Tags: python, django

this is what I'm trying to do: I have Post model and people can vote on that post. and  the calculation of that vote is done with the function in my models.py. And I want to be able to control that vote in models.py. Hopefully with code the question is more clear.

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')
    get_vote_count = models.IntegerField(default=1)



    def get_vote_count(self):
        vote_count = self.vote_set.filter(is_up=True).count() - self.vote_set.filter(is_up=False).count() +1
        if vote_count >= 0:
            return "+ " + str(vote_count)
        else:
            return "- " + str(abs(vote_count))
```

In admin.py

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['category','url','video','title',
    'content','image','get_vote_count']
    readonly_fields = ('get_vote_count',)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

Then get_vote_count shows the vote but I'm not able to control it. Can someone please teach me how?

Comment: get_vote_count as both a field and a method does not track. also, you need a second model with a foreignkey for there to be a vote_set manager.

Comment: In order to call the function, you need an event to trigger it. From the logic sounds like it's related to the voting action. Where does you voting action happen? In admin or in your app views.py method? Or somewhere else?